# how to see the elements inside a List in debugger mode In intellij IDE?

Tags: java, spring-boot, intellij-idea

I want to know wht are the elements in a list that is defined in a java program in a code base that I am working with.I tried looking at the interface where the type of the list is defined.andtried reading the stuff printed in the console when the program started running in debug mode,but to no avail .how can I see the elements inside the List in debugger mode In intellij IDE ?

Comment: cant you just set a breakpoint...and once you run in debug mode, just hover over the list variable name??

Comment: https://www.jetbrains.com/help/idea/examining-suspended-program.html#variables

Answer (score 2):

One way to accomplish this is to use the built-in debug tool. You set a breakpoint at the line where you want to debug your list.

Etc. If we have an ArrayList of strings.

```
ArrayList<String> names = new ArrayList<>();
names.add("Charles");
names.add("Peter");
names.add("Luke");
```

Then you breakpoint here `names.add("Luke");`

Then you can easily in Intellij click at the list beside the debugged line and the list shows up.
[View from IntelliJ](https://i.stack.imgur.com/2qixm.png)